# How to make a nested switch work?

Tags: java, android, nested, switch-statement

Im completely new to android development and i have some problems with a nested switch. For starts i wonder if that is possible.

Below is part of my code for a score + stats counter for a basketball game. 
So to explain you what i want to do - the user will press a button (player) and then the app disables all the buttons in the screen except of the stats buttons (such as +1point, +2points, +1assist etc)
The problem is that i cant get the program to get me in the second switch.
I could use any help, 
Thank you

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view){

    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.player1_team1:
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.player2_team1)).setEnabled(false);
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.player3_team1)).setEnabled(false);
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.player4_team1)).setEnabled(false);
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.player5_team1)).setEnabled(false);
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.player1_team2)).setEnabled(false);
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.player2_team2)).setEnabled(false);
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.player3_team2)).setEnabled(false);
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.player4_team2)).setEnabled(false);
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.player5_team2)).setEnabled(false);

            switch (view.getId()){
              case R.id.plus1p:

              thisGame.setName(getStrings(player1_team1));
              thisGame.setOnePointer(1);
              scoreTeam1 += 1;
              scoreCount1(1);
              Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "+1 point " + getStrings(player1_team1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
```

Comment: Your nested switch does not make any sense: if view.getId() == R.id.player1_team1: then view.getId() != R.id.plus1p. At least if  R.id.player1_team1 != R.id.plus1p, which is true in most cases

Comment: what should happen after stats buttons is clicked?

Comment: i will store the stats for each individual player and the team's score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You switch on the same expression in your both switches: `view.getId()`, but the `case` expression is different.

So, to get into the second `switch`'s `case` (which is embedded in the first one), `view.getId()` would have to be equal to `R.id.player1_team1` and `R.id.plus1p` at the same time. I guess these values are different, so it's not possible to get into the `case` of the second `switch`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you think i should try something like an IF statement and in this statement start a switch? Would this work?

Comment: To be honest, I do not understand what you tried to achieve with that second switch, it clearly makes no sense. So it's better to rethink what you wanted to do. Rewriting with an `if` instead of a `switch` will not help on its own.

Comment: To help you understand i want the user to press 2 buttons in two levels. First to pick the player that scored, second to tell the program if he scored a free throw or a 2 pointer

Comment: If both buttons use that same `onClick()` you showed here, then you just need one switch with 2 cases: one for one button, another for the second button.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using buttons here... and it looks like if you click on one, it disables others. Why not implement a RadioGroup with RadioButtons instead?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/playerGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/playerOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/playerTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you add 10 RadioButtons, if you select one, then you can't select the other 9, etc. You can then implement clicks within the onclick for each button. It will work 10x better than what you are trying to do.